# SharePoint and SQL Server Compact Data Files

Tags: sharepoint, sql-server-ce

I'm doing a consulting job for an organization wanting something a small step above what an Access Database would do. Generally, they want to track network lines between buildings on their campus (obviously, I'm obfuscating a bit, just go with it). And of course, they want it done in SharePoint, WITHOUT a huge software development and maintenance effort due to a limited number of users.

So, the idea is to do initial data entry via an Infopath form (and some custom code for a few basic reporting features). However, SharePoint lists aren't going to work due to the amount of data being stored.

Is it possible to publish a single SQL Server Compact sdf file to, say, a SharePoint document library to hold this data? (DBAs for the company are being obnoxious). I'm aware of the 4 GB limit on SDF files.

Comment: You should be able to upload any file. The real question is, what you intend to do with it later and what you expect sharepoint to do for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, but you could be asking for real trouble if the file size is > 30 MB.

SharePoint was designed to store "normal" sized collaboration documents which typically avg. between 800KB - 2MB.  These documents are stored as BLOBs in SQL Server and in the SharePoint Search index (if you have indexing turned on).

Comment: Can you provide details? The customer wants to store diagrams in the database, and binary data will fill the database fast.

Comment: How big are these diagrams then? If you have a SharePoint installation you'll have binary data in your databases and lots of it.. whether those DBA's like it or not.

Comment: The data would have to live on a separate database server  than the SharePoint one.